# How to create multiple simulated datasets from a random multivariate sample in R

Tags: r, random, simulation

I have created a randomised, multivariate dataset similar to the below:

```
library(JWileymisc)
librarY(MASS)
library(dplyr)

V <- matrix(c(1,0.2,0.7,
            0.2,1,0.5,
            0.7,0.5,1)
           ,3,3)
sigma <- c(60,30,45)
mu <- c(25,10,15)

Sigma <-cor2cov(V,sigma)
data <-data.frame(mvrnorm(n=5,mu,Sigma,3,3))

data <- rename(data,outcome=X1,time=X2,exposure=X3)
data$exposure <- if_else(data$exposure>15,2,1)
```

I'm then wanting to use this randomised dataset to create many multiple simulated datasets. Is there an easy way to do this using a loop? I've so far tried something of the following:

```
NSIM <- 10  #Number of data sets to simulate
set.seed(3465)
simulated_data <- rep(0, NSIM)

for (m in 1:NSIM) {
  simulated_data[m] <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n=5,mu,Sigma,3,3))
}
```

However, this doesn't really give me what I'm looking for and struggling to perform the rename/if_else components from the above. Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: There are several packages with a `cor2cov` function, the one you use should be loaded at the beginning of the script with `library(<pkgname>)`.

Comment: Thanks, I've added in the libraries at the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am using `purrr::map_dfr` to bind all the dataframes produced by the simulation (which are still identifiable and splittable by `SN`). You can perform the common operations such as `rename` and `mutate(exposure, ...)` on the merged dataframe. Eventually, you can split them using e.g. `group_by(SN)` followed by `group_split()`

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
NSIM <- 10  #Number of data sets to simulate
set.seed(3465)

map_dfr(1:NSIM,
        ~data.frame(mvrnorm(n=5,mu,Sigma,3,3)),
        .id = "SN") |>
  rename(outcome=X1,time=X2,exposure=X3) |>
  mutate(exposure = if_else(exposure>15,2,1)) |>
  sample_n(10)

##> +    SN     outcome        time exposure
##> 1   2 -35.3326059   3.2585097        1
##> 2   9  25.7304365   7.7347147        2
##> 3   7  68.3215424  -1.9466048        1
##> 4   2  77.4440558  61.0617621        2
##> 5   6 -46.3029760 -11.2115067        1
##> 6   9  92.7289232  52.0273595        2
##> 7  10   0.3859393  53.2966179        2
##> 8  10 -17.2009480 -29.6117604        1
##> 9   5  91.5425904  48.2142412        2
##> 10  3  73.6991481   0.8617149        2
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this answers my question exactly!